# consteval vs constexpr on variables

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, c++20, consteval

Is there any difference between `constexpr` and `consteval` ?

```
 consteval int x1 = 2;
 constexpr int x2 = 5;
```

Is it better to use constexpr than consteval?

Comment: I've rolled-back the question, as it was nicely answered below. Please ask a new question if you want, otherwise you may end up wasting other's time spent in writing an answer, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 38):

The [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#1) actually says:

> The consteval specifier shall be applied only to the declaration of a function or function template.

So your first example [should not compile](https://wandbox.org/permlink/gALrpEqpYjyzdK90).

---

However, you can put `consteval` or `constexpr` on functions:

```
constexpr int foo (int x) { return x; }
consteval int bar (int x) { return x; }
```

`constexpr` when applied to a function is <strike>merely</strike> largely advisory (see Davis Herring's comment) - it says to the compiler, evaluate this function call at compile time if you can.

`consteval`, on the other hand, is mandatory - it says to the compiler, generate an error if you can't evaluate this function call at compile time.

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/7WQGyN84wVoLivKj)

Comment: `constexpr` on a function is not advisory to the extent that being able to use its return value as a template argument “requires” compile-time evaluation (*i.e.*, except for an interpreter).

Comment: @DavisHerring Yes, thank you, I added a (very brief) tweak to my answer.

Comment: Where can I find what you wrote above regarding the difference between `constexpr` and `consteval` in the C++20 standard ?

Comment: @belloc This is all it seems to have to say, strangely: https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#note-3  More digging might uncover a little more.

Comment: I have just found this paper [P1073R3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1073r3.html) by R. Smith, Andrew Sutton and Daveed Vandervoorde. Thank you for having answered my comment.

Comment: @belloc YW.  Good sleuthing skills.  Why can't the standard explain this properly anywhere?  I had a bit more of a nose round but it doesn't seem to.